# Error while adding mask horizontally to an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am beginner in image processing and python. I have made a mask "maska" using `np.zeros((a,b,3),dtype=np.int16)` and added this to a cropped image `"image_cropped" using np.concatenate((cropped_image,mask),axis=1)`. But I am getting error while using added image "image_added". If I write the added image and read it again everything works fine. I am using added image as a input for stitching. Where I am doing mistake?? I have attached my code.

```
imagea = cv2.imread("images/image_495.jpg") 
image_cropped=imagea[0:1940, 1790:2590]
maska=np.zeros((1940, 1790,3),dtype=np.int16)
image_added=np.concatenate((maska,image_cropped),axis=1)
cv2.imwrite("image_added.jpg",image_added)
#imagea = cv2.imread("image_added.jpg")
```

The error I am getting:

```
error: (-215) depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_16U || depth == CV_32F in function cvtColor
```